# Decimal Format neglecting decimal 0

Tags: java, decimalformat

Hi I am trying to convert a decimal format.

```
final DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###.##");

String total = "USD"+ myFormatter.format(78.0)
```

I need to get the out put as **USD 78.00**

but I am getting the result as **USD 78**

can any one suggest me how to resolve this.

Comment: try `final DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###.00");`

Comment: Read the documentation of `DecimalFormat`. `#` means "Digit, zero shows as absent". `0` means "Digit". In other words, replace the `.##` with `.00`.

Comment: @ScaryWombat , RealSkeptic Your comments should actually be an answer, IMHO. It's simple but it solves the problem.

Comment: @Fildor the question lacks research, so I prefer not to give it an answer, so that it may be closed by the community.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I see. And on second sight, I agree with you. Casting vote ...

Comment: Like @RealSkeptic explained, the zeroes are, by class definition, neglected when using DecimalFormat. You could use `String.format("%.2f", x)` to easily get the output you want.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks any sign of research. A simple look into the docs could have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
final DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###.##");
```

to

```
final DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###.00");
```

Comment: Yes it helps too.